# How to move first line of paragraph into block created by wrapfigure?

Tags: wrapfigure

I have the following code:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}[7]{l}[3mm]{2.5cm}
\vspace{-12pt}
\includegraphics[scale=0.134]{pismena/n.png}
\end{wrapfigure}
ajskôr prišli slová, vzápätí tma.
Kračúň ubehol rýchlejšie, než sa predpokladalo. Najkratší deň v obehu     strávila
Bystrina v príprave na príchod nového obdobia. Chlapci vyrezávali drevené
dieťatko, ktoré znázorňovalo nanovo zrodené slnko, zatiaľ čo vedomci plnili
hodostoly bravčovým. Noc naplnilo veselie. Krátko po odchode kračúňa obsypali
vedomci svojich žiakov zrnom, aby podľa rodných zvykov znásobili bohatosť úrody.
Zvyšok noci Bystrinu obchádzali koledníci s piesňami a zariekadlami. Vyrezaný
symbol nového slnka niesli hrdo v~čele sprievodu. Neobišli žiaden domec,
Zimnicu, maštaľ či bydelce. Každý kút, každý tvor potreboval nádej, že Svarog
znova vyhreje matku Zem a prevezme vládu od Morany.
```

I need to move this line

```
ajskôr prišli slová, vzápätí tma.
```

to the left, into the space that is reserved by wrapfigure

Answer (score 2):

You can use a negative `\hspace` for that:

```
\hspace{-3em}ajskôr pri\u0161li slová, vzápätí tma.
```